# Control remote host's display over ssh connection

Tags: ssh, linux-mint, display

I have 2 laptops both using linux mint 20.1 and connected over local network (WiFi).

- I have a `user1@host1` and a `user2@host2`.
- I am running ssh server on host2 and client on host1.

I want to use host2's display to show the result if I send any command via ssh from host1 to host2.

Ex:

- The command which is used to switch desktop `wmctrl -s 2` should change the desktop on host2 or command `firefox` should start firefox on host2.
- I don't want to use host1's diplay for the results.

Is this possible? I have administrative and physical access on both the computers.

**What I tried?**

- I saw that the `DISPLAY` environment variable is not set so tried setting to `:0, 127.0.0.1:0` but that doesn't have any effect.
- Checked many other questions but they are trying to forward the result to their ocal display but I want the result on remote display.

Comment: This is esoteric, complex and poorly explained. You can only place a window on an x-server as the uid whom currently has a session there. That means there are a whole lot of preconditions you've mentioned in your post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am running ssh server on host2 and accessing via host1. I want to use host2's display to show the result.

1. The X server on `host2` needs to be running.
2. The user you are logged in as needs to have the authorization to use the X server. On most distros (but not all), this is done by having a "magic cookie" in `$HOME/.Xauthority`.

You can accomplish this for example by logging in as the same user you are using for ssh onto host2 from the keyboard.

3. If (1) and (2) are true, you can set `export DISPLAY=:0` after you log in with `ssh` to host2, and then any X programs spawned from this shell will use the display on host2.